# Ver ultimo registro

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

estoy intentando visualizar el ultimo registro de una tabla para mostrar la foto de ese registro en un picturebox pero el codigo solo me funciona de la siguiente forma:

```
                Ficha fco = new Ficha();

            using (Model.GRUDENTEntities db = new Model.GRUDENTEntities())
            {
                var paciente = db.Consulta.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdPaciente == idp);

                if (paciente == null)
                    return;

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(paciente.Foto))
                {
                    fco.pbDentagrama.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                }

            }

            fco.Show();
```

(idp es una variable donde guardo el id del paciente)Y asi se visualiza el registro pero no el ultimo, si intento recuperar el ultimo que seria LastOrDefault en vez de FirstOrDefault me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error dice la consulta `LastOrDefault`, en tu código, nada referido existe hay al respecto, ¿falta agregar código a la pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que la tabla Consultas tendras varios registros para un mismo cliente, en ese caso podrias usar

```
 using (Model.GRUDENTEntities db = new Model.GRUDENTEntities())
 {
     var paciente = db.Consulta.Where(x => x.IdPaciente == idp)
                               .OrderByDescending(x=> x.CampoFecha)
                               .FirstOrDefault();

      //resto codigo
```

como veras filtras por el id del paciente, ordenas de forma descendente de forma que la fecha mas alta este primero y despues tomas un solo registro

Pero igual un detalle, lo que estas recuperando son las consultas no los pacientes por eso la variable creo que esta mail nombrada

Comment: excelente, ahora funciona. muchas gracias. la variable se llama paciente para evitar confusión ya que de la consulta en si lo que me interesa es lo relacionado al paciente y asi me es mas facil recordarlo